# How to get country name from country Id in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, bind

Hello Everyone sorry for the noob question
But I am stuck with a problem. The problem is: 
I am getting country Id from database and I want to display the selected country name
here is the code

```
 $scope.Customer.CU_Country = data.cU_Country;
```

I am getting Id on html using ng-model

```
ng-model="Customer.CU_Country"
```

I want to show the country name on the basis of country idin html how can I do this?
Here the fields are

```
id and name
```

but when i display the Country in html  using 
`{{Customer.CU_Country}}`
then it is showing country id how can i replace id from name.

Comment: get both id and name from database - your `data.cU_Country` should have an object like - `{Id:1,CountryName:'India'}`

Comment: Pleas let us see your code as code snippet. may be we can answer you better. you can make an object of country contains id and title. use it in your scope. and then get the id and title from that, both. But anyway, it seems that the more explanation is needed in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use the ng-model as

```
"Customer.CU_Country.name"
```

**`DEMO`**

```js
var menuApp = angular.module("menuApp", []);
menuApp.controller("menuCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.Customer = {};
  $scope.Customer.CU_Country = {
    id: 101,
    name: "india"
  };
});;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='menuApp'>
  <div ng-controller="menuCtrl">
    <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="Customer.CU_Country.name">
    <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="Customer.CU_Country.id">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is different from the OPs question?

Comment: @SunilBN i have posted this answer after reading the comments, yes it is different. there is no way it is mentioned in the question

Comment: Same goes for my answer.

Comment: use ng-model to get the desired results